# Is it possible to implement business layer validation to the Linq2Sql classes

Tags: c#, validation, linq-to-sql

I am aware of the business layer validation for the model classes in general n-layered architectures model classes, by using validation attributes.
Now, I just i want to know if its applicable to Linq2Sql classes, as if I manually add some attributes to the class or its members, then on next addition or deletion in Dbml file, it will rewrite the designer classes, erasing my changes made.

Please help me...

Any idea , sample code or site references are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a partial class and annotate that

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;  
namespace MvcDA {
    [MetadataType(typeof(ProductMD))]
    public partial class Product {
        public class ProductMD {
            [StringLength(50),Required]
            public object Name { get; set; }
            [StringLength(15)]
            public object Color { get; set; }
            [Range(0, 9999)]
            public object Weight { get; set; }
          //  public object NoSuchProperty { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

[Validate Model Data Using DataAnnotations Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link. But the reference I am seeing is of Framework 4. Is it applicable in 3.5. Also in the reference its showing its a part of ASP Net MVC 2. I am using WebForms with L2S. Please guide

Comment: @See-Sharp yes its also applicable in 3.5 try it please